# Selecting multiple rows of items in a table

Tags: javascript

EDIT: I didn't have enough time to ask the question properly. I am rewriting the question with an image.

So, I have a table (shown below):

[image]

The data on each row are dynamically filled out.
However, if users want to delete the data (which they can), they have to delete them individually.

How can I implement the "Select" checkbox and apply the "Delete" (for example) action to the "Checked" items?

Thanks! =)

Comment: not so clear question to ask. what type of table you are talking about? is it html or what. edit your question so that negative vote doesn't occur.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was in a hurry to finish the question and did not write it properly. I updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
function inputChanged(event) {
  event.target.parentElement.parentElement.className =
    event.target.checked ? 'selected' : '';
}

function printSelected() {
  var textArea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
  textArea.value = '';

  var selectedRows = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; ++i) {
    textArea.value += selectedRows[i].textContent.trim() + '\n';
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" onchange="inputChanged(event)" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" onchange="inputChanged(event)" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="printSelected()">Print selected rows</button>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: That's exactly it. =) Sorry that my initial question was not clear and you still gave me what I was exactly looking for. That's good enough for me to get started. Thanks @trevorade